# DiagrammeR does not accept specific syntax symbols

Tags: r, diagrammer

I want to build a basic flowchart with the DiagrammeR package like below. The code chunk below works normally. But when I add "." or "=" then I get

```
Error: syntax error in line 9 near '->'
```

## working code

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# A minimal plot
DiagrammeR::grViz("digraph {

                  graph[layout = dot, rankdir = LR]

                  BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN
                  12
                  ACR50

                  BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN -> 12 -> ACR50
                  }")
```

## non-working code

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# A minimal plot
DiagrammeR::grViz("digraph {

                  graph[layout = dot, rankdir = LR]

                  population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv
                  12
                  ACR50

                  population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv -> 12 -> ACR50
                  }")
```

The result should be like:
[image]
but with population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv,12,ACR50 in the positions of a, b and c respectively.

Comment: You don't use equal signs in diagrammer canonical syntax. Use population=['text'] I'm not on my computer so can't provide a detailed answer.

Comment: In which of the two 'population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv'?

Comment: Could you explain what these arrows are implying? Also are these node labels? If yes, why have two populations?

Comment: I followed exactly the 1st example here https://mikeyharper.uk/flowcharts-in-r-using-diagrammer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? Shapes can be modified later

```
      library(DiagrammeR)
grViz(
  "digraph{
    graph[layout='dot',outputorder=edgesfirst,overlap=T,rankdir=LR]

 b[label='population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
 c [label='12']
 d[label='ACR50']
 b->c[label='link1']
 c->d[label='link2']
 }")
```

Currently:
[image]

Shape Changes: Appears nicer

```
grViz(
  "digraph{
    graph[layout='dot',outputorder=edgesfirst,overlap=T,rankdir=LR]
    node[shape='box']

 b[label='population=BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv']
 c [label='12']
 d[label='ACR50']
 b->c[label='link1']
 c->d[label='link2']
 }")
```

[image]

Comment: Edited. You can remove link1 and link2 by leaving the "label" attributes blank

Comment: I need the 'population=' as well before the 'BARI_POP4_5_PRIMARY_CN.csv'

Comment: Edited. Check if that helps!

Comment: I have another Question related to DiagrameR and I will create a new Q for that

Comment: Alright, I'm off to bed! Hopefully someone answers it. I'll be happy to whenever I see it. Cheers!